# How to set icon's background color in TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, icons

folks! I have a little bit silly question. I want to make icons in the TableViewCell
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qGk9.jpg) with background color and rounded corners. As I understood, I can use native icons defined in Xcode but i can't change background because the size of icons is wrong comparing to settings' .
How did Apple do it? They made images or it can be possible to do it via Xcode and Swift itself? Thanks

P.S. I use TableViewController with static cells, now it looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o97F6.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to make a tappable button? Or just display the `System Image` in a `UIImageView`?

Comment: I use ImageView.  https://imgur.com/kDNNGNV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll almost certainly want to use `Custom` cell style instead of `Basic`.

Add a `UIView` to use as the "rounded corners" part of the icon. Add an image view, centered in that view, for your system images. Add a label.

Basic approach (using static table view, as you mentioned):

[image]

Here's the code for the "rounded view" - configured as `@IBDesignable` so you can see it in Storyboard:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

and here's the full Storyboard source to get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="WtW-LE-VWk">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="qc4-73-L2A">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="27Q-AC-Jb0" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="static" style="insetGrouped" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="18" sectionFooterHeight="18" id="IFE-zD-nEK">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <sections>
                            <tableViewSection id="LW5-bS-sCO">
                                <cells>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="55" id="sxh-Sk-bNM">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="18" width="343" height="55"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="sxh-Sk-bNM" id="H0b-UB-YIR">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="343" height="55"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pz9-zZ-kOc" customClass="RoundedView" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="32" height="32"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="YcQ-rh-NHn"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="32" id="jck-uB-cqC"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="bolt.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JeW-kU-JcB">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="23.5" y="16" width="17" height="21.5"/>
                                                    <color key="tintColor" red="0.3623966575" green="0.55341643100000004" blue="0.62130481000000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                </imageView>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="clR-2W-9tl">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="56" y="16.5" width="295" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.10831441729999999" green="0.10833679879999999" blue="0.11850371210000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="JeW-kU-JcB" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="centerY" id="9cf-bd-KWA"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="H0b-UB-YIR" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="BDH-af-jJ9"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="bottom" id="DgH-q4-Bu8"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="clR-2W-9tl" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="centerY" id="JZT-iV-Btg"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="JeW-kU-JcB" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Qwc-Ki-K4f"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="clR-2W-9tl" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="hSO-P4-ERd"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="clR-2W-9tl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="l5p-PI-tUW"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pz9-zZ-kOc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="H0b-UB-YIR" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="qlH-ce-h5Q"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="55" id="Vlt-uX-i4X">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="73" width="343" height="55"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="Vlt-uX-i4X" id="FvK-6i-Ped">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="343" height="55"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="C2d-Cl-1Vf" customClass="RoundedView" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="32" height="32"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.98642545940000004" green="0.74593347310000002" blue="0.57237553600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="EIW-gj-enD"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="32" id="Iok-r4-lBV"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="star.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4yK-2K-GYt">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="21" y="17" width="22" height="20"/>
                                                    <color key="tintColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                </imageView>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GAQ-UB-6qR">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="56" y="16.5" width="295" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.10831441729999999" green="0.10833679879999999" blue="0.11850371210000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="4yK-2K-GYt" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="0r3-0F-9sC"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="GAQ-UB-6qR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="8wC-js-QNq"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="bottom" id="CY5-96-3hI"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="GAQ-UB-6qR" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="H0b-Vp-33Y"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="FvK-6i-Ped" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="eNy-0L-bfh"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="4yK-2K-GYt" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="centerX" id="jZa-av-lov"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="FvK-6i-Ped" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="pn9-As-KE5"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="GAQ-UB-6qR" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="C2d-Cl-1Vf" secondAttribute="centerY" id="tie-Yc-jw2"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </tableViewSection>
                            <tableViewSection headerTitle="Section Header" id="9ZP-e3-t3g">
                                <cells>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="55" id="UZ5-EZ-H5Y">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="184" width="343" height="55"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="UZ5-EZ-H5Y" id="ABd-id-DDv">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="343" height="55"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KaK-vV-uVH" customClass="RoundedView" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="11" width="32" height="32"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.83741801979999997" green="0.83743780850000005" blue="0.83742713930000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="AM4-pp-HAO"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="32" id="UcR-9P-CI0"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="dollarsign.circle.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="U8c-Bp-yMq">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="21" y="17.5" width="20" height="19"/>
                                                    <color key="tintColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                </imageView>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="12T-Ga-3Q3">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="55" y="16.5" width="265" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.10831441729999999" green="0.10833679879999999" blue="0.11850371210000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="U8c-Bp-yMq" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="centerX" id="4um-Hn-oWU"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KaK-vV-uVH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ABd-id-DDv" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="COf-5P-6Uz"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="12T-Ga-3Q3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="N47-hy-itj"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="U8c-Bp-yMq" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="ThJ-LN-iPp"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KaK-vV-uVH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ABd-id-DDv" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="Ya3-A5-iUX"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="12T-Ga-3Q3" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="bJy-ZC-oKM"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="12T-Ga-3Q3" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="fM8-fC-9K3"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="KaK-vV-uVH" secondAttribute="bottom" id="kvZ-QP-3Ai"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="55" id="Wm0-f3-rlS">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="239" width="343" height="55"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="Wm0-f3-rlS" id="EEv-Md-d6p">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="343" height="55"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7MA-zO-mfe" customClass="RoundedView" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="11" width="32" height="32"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="Gvh-tX-e0t"/>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="32" id="fRi-hL-8PM"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                </view>
                                                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="globe" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wSv-n8-uf2">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="21.5" y="18" width="19.5" height="18.5"/>
                                                    <color key="tintColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                </imageView>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pnh-HT-JDj">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="55" y="16.5" width="265" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.10831441729999999" green="0.10833679879999999" blue="0.11850371210000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pnh-HT-JDj" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="centerY" id="2MY-6y-DAB"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="bottom" id="7ES-kW-TRx"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="wSv-n8-uf2" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="centerY" id="97K-2Q-0GG"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="7MA-zO-mfe" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="EEv-Md-d6p" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="9c3-12-fqv"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="pnh-HT-JDj" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="FgF-cy-Ex8"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="7MA-zO-mfe" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="EEv-Md-d6p" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="bgS-Cz-64I"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="wSv-n8-uf2" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="centerX" id="lX8-69-qVu"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="pnh-HT-JDj" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="7MA-zO-mfe" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="xSU-A1-3Is"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </tableViewSection>
                        </sections>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="27Q-AC-Jb0" id="qb8-kc-ZDj"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="27Q-AC-Jb0" id="UJ5-Rn-UKL"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="DrP-bd-JmI"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="MZt-E3-d6F" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1024.8" y="89.505247376311857"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="OjR-lK-dFV">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="WtW-LE-VWk" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="djt-qE-oyG">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="27Q-AC-Jb0" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="GGU-bG-Zsb"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="K6D-eL-jlc" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="85.599999999999994" y="89.505247376311857"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="bolt.fill" catalog="system" width="101" height="128"/>
        <image name="dollarsign.circle.fill" catalog="system" width="128" height="121"/>
        <image name="globe" catalog="system" width="128" height="121"/>
        <image name="star.fill" catalog="system" width="128" height="116"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to build the icons yourself. Just use Sketch or Illustrator, add a new textfield in **SF Pro Text** on top of a rectangle and paste the icons from SFSymbols in. Export it as an PDF and you can use it as an icon in your app.

[Here is a screenshot of the setup in Sketch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4qGN.jpg)

Just a text layer on top of an rectangle with rounded corners